# Wrong Week of year returned using ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear()

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core, calendar, .net-5

I'm here to ask some help about getting the Week of Year for a given date using c# on .net core. For some reason when I use ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear() I get wrong values.

For instance on this calendar that I got from this [website](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html):

[image]

We can see that 52th week lasts until Sat, 25th of Dec 2021. But when I run the code below I get 51 as the week day.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-24"))); // 51 // Should be 52
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-25"))); // 51
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-26"))); // 51 // Should be 1 (or 53)
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-27"))); // 52
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-31"))); // 52
}

internal static DateTime ToDate(string s)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(s);
}

internal static int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime date)
{
    return System.Globalization.ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(date);
}
```

[Also sharing the same code here so you can easily reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/utIwY9)

Does anyone know how to get the correct values?

- 52 for days between 19 and 25 Dec.
- 1 for days between 26 Dec to 01 Jan 2022.

PS: I tried using `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` but then I get 53 for days starting on 26 Dec. Therefore I searched and found about ISOWeek.

PS2: My dotnet version: 5.0.102

Comment: There are various ways to calculate week number. For example .NET has another "week number" in [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear?view=net-5.0). The site doesn't specify what algorithm it is using.

Comment: Yes @xanatos I tried it, as mentioned on my first PS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this question is that I wanted to create a method to compare whether 2 dates were in the same Week. Using the default configuration I was getting different week days even if they were on the same week.

I made some changes to my code, set the default DayOfWeek as Sunday and now seems to work as expected.

I will share the entire code. Might be helpful for someone in the future :).

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2020-12-27"))); 
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-01-01"))); 
    
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-12-30"))); 
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2022-01-01"))); 
    
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-01-31"))); 
    Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-02-01"))); 
}

internal DateTime ToDate(string s)
{
    return DateTime.Parse(s);
}

internal int GetWeekOfYear(DateTime date)
{
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the source of your confusion is a discrepancy between `GetWeekOfYear` and the site you are using. `GetWeekOfYear` considers the first week of the year to be the first *full* week of the year beginning on a Monday. In your example code, if you add:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-01-01"))); // 53
Console.WriteLine(GetWeekOfYear(ToDate("2021-01-04"))); // 1
```

This is because while January 1st is the first day of the year, in 2021 that day falls on a Friday. `GetWeekOfYear` considers that a part of the *final week of the previous year*, so the first week of the year will begin on the following Monday (January 4th, in this case).

By contrast, plugging January 1st, 2021 into your linked calendar website lists the week with that date being "Week 1", demonstrating that that website considers the week containing the first day of the year to be the first week of that year. As such, the two systems will only agree on what "Week 1" is when the first day of a given year happens to fall on a Monday.

Neither source is plainly wrong. They just make different assumptions over what the first week of the year is.

Comment: You're right. The website was using a different configuration but I didn't realise it. I just posted a reply with some changes I made. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score -1):

The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) lists the existence of three algorithms for calculating the week number: ISO-8601, Middle Eastern, Western traditional. We don't know which one the site is using, because it doesn't tell.

If you "expand for more options" you'll see that the site is highly customizable:

[image]

Still, with all these customizations, a simple combobox listing some predefined algorithms is missing. Do you know how to "program" it to have the ISO Week Number? I don't, nor I want to learn, when there are other sites that will give you **exactly** what you want.

For example [this site](http://myweb.ecu.edu/mccartyr/isowdcal.html) that declares to calculate the week number with the ISO formula gives 51 for 2021-12-24.

Mmmh... I'll say that with these settings the site gives the ISO Week:

[image]